# Toggle child nodes on checking checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making this recursive listview where I am trying to show/hide the child components if the parent checkbox is toggled. I did something wrong here that I can't make it work anymore. The problem seems to be with the argument of `onClick()` function in the input tag. I am new in React and can't find out how to fix this problem. Can I get some help on how to do that?

```
export default class MyList extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          visible: true
        };
      }

      toggle = () => {
        this.setState(
          {visible: !this.state.visible}
        );
      };

      render() {
        var style;
        if (!this.state.visible) {
          style = {display: "none"};
        }

        var node = this.props.data;
        return(
          <div>
          <ul style={style}>
          {
            Object.keys(this.props.data).map(function(key){
            return (
                <li key={key}><input type="checkbox" onClick={MyList.toggle}/>
                  <label>{key}</label> :
                  {typeof node[key] === 'object' ? <MyList data = {node[key]} /> : node[key]}
                </li>
              );
            })
          }
          </ul>
          </div>
        );
      }
}
```

Comment: why would you want `MyList` to render itself?

Comment: I'm not sure. I didn't  know any alternate way.

Comment: to do what exactly?

Comment: I am making a recursive listview and intend to hide child nodes when parent checkbox is clicked. I am checking if the child node is an object, the component calls itself

Comment: and you want to hide __ONLY__ the checkbox that was clicked?

Comment: I want to hide the child nodes. I want to make the list collapsible, that is.

Comment: As a reference, I have a working example of recursive collapsible React app https://codepen.io/kunukn/pen/VrWLyY?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do.
I tried to understand as you see in our conversation in comments but i still don't get the idea.
Never the less, just to answer your question and point you in the right direction, your problem is with this line:

```
onClick={MyList.toggle}
```

`toggle` is a method that belongs to the **instance** of the class and it isn't a static member, hence you must call it within the context of the instance.
One way of diong it is to use the `this` as the reference to the current instance. the problem is that you are using anonymous function inside `.map` of `Object.keys` and `this` is not referencing the instance anymore.
To make sure `this` is the reference of the class instance you can use an arrow function which is using a lexical context for `this`.

```
{Object.keys(this.props.data).map(key => {
            return (
              <li key={key}>
                <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.toggle} />
                ...
```

Or do it the "old and ugly style" with `var that = this` on the top line of the function. (i prefer the second option).
By the way, you put the `style` object on the `ul` element, that means the entire `ul` will be hidden after one click. not sure this is your intentions.

Here is a running example of your code:

```js
class MyList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: true
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  };

  render() {
    var style;
    if (!this.state.visible) {
      style = { display: "none" };
    }

    var node = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div>
        <ul style={style}>
          {Object.keys(this.props.data).map(key => {
            return (
              <li key={key}>
                <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.toggle} />
                <label>{key}</label> :
                {typeof node[key] === "object" ? (
                  <MyList data={node[key]} />
                ) : (
                  node[key]
                )}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyList data={[1, 2, 3]} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> trying to make something like [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/XX8mw/) but instead with
>   checkboxes but I am unable to collapse the list.

Here is a version of the code in the link with checkbox inputs:

```js
class TreeNode extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: true
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible });
  };

  render() {
    var childNodes;
    var classObj;

    if (this.props.node.childNodes != null) {
      childNodes = this.props.node.childNodes.map(function(node, index) {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <TreeNode node={node} />
          </li>
        );
      });

      classObj = {
        togglable: true,
        "togglable-down": this.state.visible,
        "togglable-up": !this.state.visible
      };
    }

    var style;
    if (!this.state.visible) {
      style = { display: "none" };
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h5 className={classNames(classObj)}>
          <input
            checked={this.state.visible}
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={this.toggle}
          />
          {this.props.node.title}
        </h5>
        <ul style={style}>{childNodes}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

var tree = {
  title: "howdy",
  childNodes: [
    { title: "bobby" },
    {
      title: "suzie",
      childNodes: [
        {
          title: "puppy",
          childNodes: [{ title: "dog house" }]
        },
        { title: "cherry tree" }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

ReactDOM.render(<TreeNode node={tree} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}

h3 {
  color: #BF616A;
}

.togglable {
  color: #D78770;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.togglable-down::after,
.togglable-up::after {
  font-size: 8px;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.togglable-down::after {
  content: "▼";
  display: inline-block;
}

.togglable-up::after {
  content: "▶";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.5/dedupe.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You are right, I wasn't getting how to call toggle() method with this. I'm sorry about all the confusion. I am trying to make something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssorallen/XX8mw/) but instead with checkboxes but I am unable to collapse the list. Not sure where to put style attribute.

Comment: Thanks, man. I already have made such collapsible list you mentioned in your last comment but I am trying to make it a general treeview that accepts all patterns of attributes and prints values of nodes. That is the reason I changed the code and having trouble ever since. An example is:
  var myNode={
          "pager": {
          "page": 1,
          "nextPage": "some_page"
        },
          "groups": [
          {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "One"
          },
          {
            "number": "2",
            "name": "Two"
          },
         ]
    }

Comment: any chance to have a version that uses hooks ?